# Please add mobile version to the help center

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, help-center

Currently, the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) does not have any mobile theme, except parts like [badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

We do have link to help center in the mobile theme footer:

> [image]

So can we please have mobile version of the help center pages?

Comment: Does any of the help center have a mobile theme?

Comment: Some pages aren't available on mobile and it falls back to desktop as a reserve. This is much better than the page just being unavailable on mobile

Comment: If it's as-designed then I stand corrected

Comment: @animuson yes, [badges list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) does have mobile theme and it's part of the help center.

Comment: @conorgriffin I've made this into a general feature request, hope it's OK?

Comment: Oops... found the dupe just now, it's also dupe of the original version of this question.